# Why does fs << reinterpret_cast<char*>(&something) produce unreadabble output?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

everyone. I am having a hard time understanding what reinterpret_cast is doing. I have this piece of code:

```
 unsigned int no = 10;
    ofstream fs = ofstream("output.out", ios_base::out);
    if (!fs.bad())
    {
        fs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&no), sizeof(int)); // Line 1
        fs << no; 
    }
    fs.close();
```

Could someone explain to me what Line 1 is supposed to write? I ran the code and the output was not readable. Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This writes the integer as binary not text.

Comment: @M.M: *sigh*. he seems not to know what the code does...

Comment: Can you explain why you would do this and why you expect it to do anything sensible? This seems like obvious nonsense. Why do you have this piece of code? Where did it come from?

Comment: David, it's not my code. I'm working on past papers for my future exam and the question was "What does this line produce"? I figured it doesn't make sense, I just didn't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the compiler to act as if `&no` was a pointer to a `char`, but it's not. So you get nonsense that varies depending on platform details. Your platform's internal mechanism for storing information is not human-readable.